# Settings module not found deploying django on a shared server

Tags: python, django, fastcgi

I'm trying to deploy my django project on a shared hosting as describe [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#running-django-on-a-shared-hosting-provider-with-apache)

I have my project on /home/user/www/testa

I'm using this script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

sys.path.append("/home/user/bin/python")

sys.path.append('/home/user/www/testa')


os.chdir("/home/user/www/testa")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "settings.py"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

And here's the error I get when trying to run it from shell:

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 558, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 1118, in handler
  File "/home/user/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 230, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/user/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 33, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
  File "/home/user/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 269, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/home/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/user/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 75, in __init__
    raise ImportError, "Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings.py' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named settings.py
Content-Type: text/html



Unhandled Exception

Unhandled Exception
An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Running the script from the browser just gives me an internal server error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "settings.py"
```

should be more like

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "settings"
```

based on how you're setting up `sys.path`.  That environment variable is supposed to contain the path to the module *as it should be imported by Python*, not the actual filename of the module.

Basically, the way you've got it now is making Django do something like this internally:

```
import settings.py
```

I.e., it's trying to import a `py` module from inside a `settings` module.